# Нужно организовать динамическое создание страниц типа TabbedPage или CarouselPage для заполнения данными. Xamarin MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

Нужно организовать динамическое создание страниц типа TabbedPage или  CarouselPage для заполнения данными. Xamarin MVVM.
Суть в создании страниц с одинаковой разметкой для создания тестов с вопросами и несколькими ответами, количество страниц зависит от того сколько указал пользователь.

Comment: Создавайте, в чем загвоздка?

Comment: начинающий программист, мне не хватает знаний, я вроде бы представляю как это должно быть, но не могу реализовать

Comment: создайте в коде новую страницу типа TabbedPage и добавьте ей в цикле необходимое количество нужных страниц. XAML вам там не нужен.